# Do not start more than one power automate job for many sharepoint updates

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I use Power Automate to refresh a PowerBI dashboard when I update its input files on Sharepoint.
Since the inputs are generated via another automated process, the updates follow each other very closely, which triggers the start of one Power Automate job per updated file.

This situation leads to failed jobs since they are all running at the same time. Even worse, the first job succeeds but the refresh then happens when not all files are updated yet. It is also a waste, since I would only need one to run.

To accomodate for that, I tried to introduce a delay in the job. This makes sure that when the first job runs, refreshing powerBI will work. Howerver, the subsequent runs all fail, so I would still like to find a way not to run them at all.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction ?

Comment: Hi, may I know if the solution I provided below works ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I will try it out and keep you posted !

Comment: Setting the max number of concurrent jobs to 1 makes it so that no two jobs run at the same time, so there are no job fails. However, the subsequent jobs still run, only at a few minutes interval of each other.
Since I also get a notification at the end of a successful run and the work is already done anyway, this is not ideal for me.

Comment: Hi midemarc, I'm a little confused about your requirements. Do you mean the input files on sharepoint will be updated multiple times, but you just want the power automate run once after the last update of input files ?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have made that clearer: many files are updated in a short timeframe (few seconds). I use power automate to ask powerBI to take those changes into account.
Once the power bi dashboard is refreshed (it sees all files at once), I don't need to do that again for all files.

Comment: May I know the interval you set for the trigger in your power automate ? Is it possible to change the interval to a longer time(such as 1 hour) ? Then the trigger will check every 1 hour, and if the files update happens in a matter of seconds, each update will not trigger the power automate.

Comment: I didn't use an interval, I use the Sharepoint connector to start the job when a file of my folder is updated. I use a delay in the job steps to wait for concurrent file updates to be done. That way, the first job has all the information needed to update the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement, you can set the Share Point trigger can run only 1 instance at same time. Please refer to the steps below:

**1.** Click "**...**" button of the trigger and click "**Settings**".
[image]

**2.** Enable "Concurrency Control" limit and set `Degree of Parallelism` as `1`.
[image]

Then your logic app can not run multiple instances at same time.